# wso2 App Management UI empty

Tags: exception, wso2-iot

After updating an Entreprise Android App
the App Management Web page is blank
and many exception in wso2carbon.log

```
TID: [0] [EMM] [2015-02-10 14:03:08,054]  INFO {JAGGERY.modules.store:js} -  Tenant ID: -1234 {JAGGERY.modules.store:js}
TID: [0] [EMM] [2015-02-10 14:03:08,060] ERROR {org.jaggeryjs.hostobjects.xhr.XMLHttpRequestHostObject} -  Stream closed {org.jaggeryjs.hostobjects.xhr.XMLHttpRequestHostObject}
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:162)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:325)
```

where is the trouble ? how can i find what is wrong ?
I checked the CPU usage on server side the java process heat 100% CPU

Answer (score 0):

for me it was the hostname who caused the problem, seems app management call a hardcoded link, so if your server can access the url via a loopback you have a harpinning problem, solved by setting hostname to 127.0.0.1 in host file on the ubuntu :)

if it's of any help :)